# angular open non hash urls

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know I can remove `#` by enabling html5 mode, but I only want to modify a url. When I open `http://localhost:9000/#/ds` or `http://localhost:9000/`, it navigates to `http://localhost:9000/#/ds` but when I try to open `http://localhost:9000/sometag` then it not loads at all. I want it to be opened as `http://localhost:9000/#/sometag`
I'm using `ui-route`. Here is my code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', ['$state', ($state) ->
            $state.transitionTo('ds')
        ])

        $urlRouterProvider.when('', ['$state', ($state) ->
            $state.transitionTo('ds')
        ])
```

Note: `sometag` is a pattern, mean it could be anything just like some id `/:id`

Comment: unless you have html5 mode enabled, these routes are interpreted by your server, and ignored by the client framework, by design.

Comment: when i enabled html5 mode it opens ok without hash, but when i paste a url, then it not opens

Comment: so what is the response you get when you have html5 enabled and paste the URL?

Comment: response is `Cannot GET /ds`

Comment: hmm this needs a lot more context to really discover what your issue is.  Is the error coming from your server or angular? is this ds state actually available to be navigated to?  The purpose of # urls is to trigger JavaScript logic to avoid a page reload, but if it's the initial load of the page, it wouldn't be appropriate anyway.  There's a piece missing here somewhere.

Comment: is server set up to manage the virtual directories ?

Comment: no I did not changed anything on server. I'm just implementing client side

Comment: `http://localhost:9000/` opens `http://localhost:9000/ds` but when i directly try to open `http://localhost:9000/ds` then it gives error

Comment: server doesn't know about the virtual directories is why. You need to mod-rewrite back to entry point of your app

Comment: so there is no solution to just modify url to add a `#`?

Comment: just adding a `#` to the url wouldn't help, if the route that the `#` is triggering isn't an entry point for your app.